# Missing SELinux dependency for snapd

Tags: linux, centos, package-management

Following the instructions [here (computingforgeeks.com)](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-snapd-snap-applications-centos-7/) to install snap on CentOS 8, I run into the following snag when I run `sudo dnf -y install snapd`:

```
Error: 
 Problem: package snapd-2.42.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires snapd-selinux = 2.42.1-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides selinux-policy-base >= 3.14.3-20.el8 needed by snapd-selinux-2.42.1-1.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Anyone know an easy way to solve this? the wanted dependency does not seem to be installable for similar reasons as well.

Comment: CentOS has some delay compared to RHEL, looking at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/ the latest is selinux-policy-3.14.1-61.el8_0.2.noarch.rpm .  my guess is they didnt test the new package on centos8, only on rhel8